# Como verificar se o valor de uma key existe em um mapa em c++

Tags: c++, grafo, hashmap

Estou fazendo um TAD de grafos e uso uma estrutura map para mapear o ID de um vértice para o seu índice na matriz de adjacências e para fazer isso eu preciso antes verificar se dado o id do vértice ele já está adicionado ao grafo, então como eu posso verificar se existe um valor mapeado para determinada key?
o código é mais ou menos algo assim

```
bool Graph::add_edge(vertex o, vertex d){
    ///if(index[o] existe)
    /// if(index[d] existe)
        ///add aresta
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta usar o método `find` do `std::map`. Isso vai retornar um iterador, se o iterador não for igual ao `end()` do seu map, então quer dizer que o valor da key existe. Exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;


void existe(const string& nome, const map<string, int>& pessoas)
{
    auto res = pessoas.find(nome);
    if (res != pessoas.end())
        cout << "-- " << nome << " esta no std::map!\n";
    else
        cout << "-- " << nome << " nao esta no std::map!\n";
}


int main()
{
    map<string, int> pessoas;

    pessoas["john"] = 22;
    pessoas["mary"] = 30;
    pessoas["ethan"] = 40;
    pessoas["larry"] = 12;

    existe("john", pessoas);
    existe("peter", pessoas);
    existe("larry", pessoas);
    existe("alice", pessoas);

    return 0;
}
```